# Hibernate: org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: null id in com.xxx.Bean entry

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, mysql5, hibernate3

I was faced to the following error:

```
com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.UnexpectedException: Service method 'public abstract void com.xxx.Service.save(com.xxx.Bean)' threw an unexpected exception: org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: null id in com.xxx.Bean entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.encodeResponseForFailure(RPC.java:385)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:588)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:208)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:248)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:306)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:541)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:383)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:243)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:288)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Caused by: org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: null id in com.xxx.Bean entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.checkId(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:82)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.getValues(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:190)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.onFlushEntity(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:147)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEntities(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:219)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEverythingToExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:50)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1216)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:383)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:133)
    at com.xxx.ServiceImpl.save(ServiceImpl.java:32)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    ... 23 more
```

Here is MySQL table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE `tblARF` (
  `ARF_ID` bigint(19) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ARF_MANUFACTURER_MNF_ID` bigint(19) NOT NULL,
  ...
  PRIMARY KEY (`ARF_ID`),
  KEY `ARF_MANUFACTURER_MNF_ID` (`ARF_MANUFACTURER_MNF_ID`)
)
```

And here is Hibernate mapping:

```
<class name="Bean" table="tblARF">
  <id name="key" type="long" unsaved-value="null">
    <column name="ARF_ID" not-null="true"/>
    <generator class="identity" />
  </id>
<many-to-one column="ARF_MANUFACTURER_MNF_ID" name="manufacturer"
    class="ManufacturerBean" not-null="true" lazy="false"/>
...
</class>
```

Java code:

```
Session s = hibernate.getCurrentSession();
Transaction t = s.beginTransaction();
s.merge(bean.getManufacturer());
s.save(bean);
t.commit();
```

I noticed that if I remove `KEY ARF_MANUFACTURER_MNF_ID (ARF_MANUFACTURER_MNF_ID)` than `AssertionFailure` doesn't happen. Is there a way to avoid this error without removing the KEY?

[This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1838520) doesn't work for me unfortunately.

Comment: `org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: null id in com.xxx.Bean entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)`  - There must be an second (more intresting) (Assertion)Exception -- Please post it too

Comment: answer updated - (and sorry I have overlooked the relevant part)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer was found here:
https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=1009141

> 'order' is a reserved keyword in SQL
>   so if you want to use if as a column
>   name it needs to be quoted. See
>   http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/mapping.html#mapping-quotedidentifiers for instructions how to
>   enabled this.

Answer (score 2):

The Exception you have posted said what the problem is:

`Caused by: org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: null id in com.xxx.Bean entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)`

In Hibernate you have to throw away the Hibernate Session after a Session related Exception occures.

*But I guess that is not your question.*

You need to set the ID of your `Bean` or use `<generator class="native" />` (`@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)`) instead.

**Added**
try to replace: `merge` by `save`

Comment: Actually I have tried this a bit earlier. I discovered that the problem is caused by `<many-to-one column="ARF_MANUFACTURER_MNF_ID"` but not by primary key.

Comment: So you may have two problems. But you are right, the behavior you desciped looks like you did not set the ManufacturerBean, so you need to set it, or remove the Not Null constraint of your forain key field.

Comment: The mystery is that I have set it and it is not null, but hibernate throws AssertionError :)

Comment: @Antonio: Looks like you need to check the SQL statements, may this gives you a hint. (and I hope you Perist the ManuacturingBean first)

Comment: Antonio: try to replace: `merge` by `save`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether it's related to your problem, but note the wrong usage of `merge()`.

`merge()` doesn't make the object passed into it persistent, it returns another instance with the same state instead, so you should write

```
bean.setManufacturer(s.merge(bean.getManufacturer()));
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I have tried and it does not help as well.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the real error lies somewhere else. To check the exact error use Debug mode and make use of printstacktrace() method of exception. It gives you the more detailed reason. In my case I had used String where the column was of type int.