# why generationtype.sequence in mysql doesn't work?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

i am developing an application using hibernate 4.1, zk 6.5 and mySql 9.3, I tried using generationtype.sequence in my code but unfortunately it returned an error, after doing some research on the internet I found out that MySQL doesn't support sequence so instead I used  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) and it fixed my problem! but I was wondering why sequence doesn't work with mySql ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hibernate problems with Auto Increment ID MYSQL 5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1838520/hibernate-problems-with-auto-increment-id-mysql-5)

Comment: MySQL 9.3? I thought the version numbers currently were around 5 and 6...

Comment: You need the "identity" mapping for an auto increment column.

Comment: A sequence doesn't work with MySql because nobody built it into the database.  The code isn't there.  You answered your own question, `I found out that MySQL doesn't support sequence`

Comment: this link is very helpful :
http://www.roseindia.net/hibernate/hibernateidgeneratorelement.shtml

Answer (score 2):

I'm leaving an answer, so this question can be removed from the "unanswered" SOF category.
KevinB, you can leave an answer, and I'll upvote it.
I just want this question to be closed out...more than (me) "getting points".

But here is a concrete answer and reference.

Short Version:

MySql does not have "true" sequences.  It uses a Sequence-via-a-Table workaround...that is a bottleneck if you're trying to do alot of JPA batching.

https://thorben-janssen.com/5-things-you-need-to-know-when-using-hibernate-with-mysql/

> 1. Mappings: Primary Keys The efficient handling and creation of primary keys are a basic but one of the most important parts of an
>    application.
>
> The @GeneratedValue annotation of the JPA specification allows you to
> define the strategy you want to use to create unique primary key
> values. You can choose between SEQUENCE, IDENTITY, TABLE, and AUTO.
>
> In general, I recommend using the SEQUENCE strategy because it allows
> Hibernate to use JDBC batching and other optimization strategies that
> require the delayed execution of SQL INSERT statements.

**But you can’t use this strategy with a *MySQL* database. It requires a database sequence, and MySQL doesn’t support this feature.**