# Duplicate key or integrity constraint violation message from server in Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I'm new to Hibernate. I'm trying to insert records into my MySQL DB. The first record was inserted properly when I run the Java application, and when I change the details in the code and try to run it again. It throws me error of Duplicate key or integrity constraint. My XML is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="com.college.Student" table="STUDENT">
<id column="ID" name="id" type="long" />
<property column="STUDENT_NAME" name="name" type="string" />
<property column="DEGREE" name="degree" type="string" />
<property column="ROLL" name="roll" type="string" />
<property column="PHONE" name="phone" type="string" />
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

I guess I need to change in this configuration file or Hibernate.cfg.xml because its a primary key . Please suggest me.

Following is the error

```
WARN: SQL Error: 1062, SQLState: 23000
Feb 18, 2016 11:49:36 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: Duplicate key or integrity constraint violation message from server:  "Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'"
Feb 18, 2016 11:49:36 AM  org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl release
INFO: HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
Feb 18, 2016 11:49:36 AM org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$5 mapManagedFlushFailure
ERROR: HHH000346: Error during managed flush [could not execute statement]
Exception in thread "main"  org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:112)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you haven't incremented your primary key column, you will have to do something like this

```
<id column="ID" name="id" type="long" >
     <generator class="increment" />
</id>
```

Comment: Whats the diff between class="increment" and class="native"

Comment: @Syed looks like `native` is [not a good choose](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1838520/hibernate-problems-with-auto-increment-id-mysql-5) for MySQL

Comment: @v.ladynev Why? Any special reason?

Comment: @Syed See the link :)

Comment: @v.ladynev what link?

Comment: @Syed [not a good choose](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1838520/hibernate-problems-with-auto-increment-id-mysql-5)

Answer (score 0):

You need to give generator for primary key of your table which will auto generated.

```
<id name="id" type="int" column="id">
     <generator class="native"/>
  </id>
```

[Read this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_mapping_files.htm)

Comment: better to use JPA, it will save your time to maintain XML files.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have an auto increment for an `id` column.

For MySQL the best choice is to use `identity` generator, because of MySQL supports it natively.

```
<id column="ID" name="id" type="long">
    <generator class="identity"/>
</id>
```

Hibernate will create a table with `auto_increment` column and MySQL will care about auto increment `id`

```
create table STUDENT (
    ID bigint not null auto_increment,
    ...
)
```

Using other generators is not optimal, because of Hibernate will use additional queries and a table (`hibernate_sequence`) to increment `id`.